# Spring Cloud Brixton.M3 Dependency Issue

Tags: spring-cloud

I am migrating our application from Spring Cloud Angel.SR2 to Brixton.M3 and I have encountered an issue with one of the transitive dependencies included as part of the spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server artifact. Specifically, the artifact "jackson-dataformat-xml" is marked as a runtime dependency.

This manifests as an exception during startup of my discovery service:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:59) ~[jackson-dataformat-xml-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder$XmlObjectMapperInitializer.create(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:775) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:550) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration.java:68) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
```

I am able to fix this issue by adding an explicit compile time dependency to my project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Ideally, this would be defined in the spring cloud dependencies, similar to how it is done in the org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.Release.pom

Before I submit an issue on github, I want to make sure I am not missing something.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand why this is a spring-cloud issue?

Comment: Ugh, on further research, the project has a parent pom that was explicitly defining a older version of some of the jackson libraries.